# Benefits of using an array_pop?

Tags: php, arrays, vbulletin

I have an old vBulletin product I am upgrading and while playing around with it, I managed to get it functioning a couple of ways.

The original outdated code:

```
$tests = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) FROM `" . TABLE_PREFIX . "something`");
$test = (mysql_result($tests, 0, 0));
```

The way I'm used to updating these types of products:

```
$tests = $vbulletin->db->query_read("SELECT count(*) FROM `" . TABLE_PREFIX . "something`");
$test = $vbulletin->db->num_rows($tests);
```

I found this sample code though and was also able to get my product working using this line instead:

```
$test = array_pop($db->query_first("SELECT count(*) FROM `" . TABLE_PREFIX . "something`", DBARRAY_NUM)) ;
```

Which leads me to my question:
Aside from being less characters of code, is there any benefit to using an `array_pop` in this manner?

Comment: Query_first() returns an array, and you just pop off the last element and write it into $test. You could also do `($db->query_first("SELECT count(*) FROM `" . TABLE_PREFIX . "something`", DBARRAY_NUM))[0];` instead. Btw. I don't see what you are "updating". There's no database update.